# Mouse Freezes Randomly 

Tags: mouse

I can run for many days without any issues, but then, like today, my Logitech USB mouse will freeze in motion every 60-90 seconds.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you replaced the battery?

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging and plugging it back it or switching to a different mouse.

I am having the same problem but my mouse is not wireless.  It's a simple Dell USB mouse.  Machine is HP elite 477c, 8 GB RAM, i5, running Ubuntu 12.10. It doesn't freeze as often as 60-9090 seconds but it is often enough it is aggravating and makes playing games especially difficult. USB keyboard still works and programs seems responsive.  My guaranteed fix is to unplug the mouse and plug it back in.

While that is hardly a solution to the problem I did switch to a wireless mouse several hours ago and it hasn't locked up.  Insistently I swapped with another PC here running Windows and neither have a problem now.